# How long does it take for an Amazon S3 object redirect to take effect?

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I have a very simple, static web site in an Amazon S3 bucket.
Everything works, or used to work, except that one redirect does not work any more.

to be more specific:
I have one object, /A.zip, say, in the bucket.
It used to redirect to /A-v1.1.zip. That worked so far.

Now, I have just changed the redirect for A.zip to redirect to /A-v1.2.zip.
And I have deleted the object A-v1.1.zip .

But it seems that A.zip is still pointing to A-v1.1.zip!
Some browsers still load the old A-v1.1.zip when I try to get A.zip (probably out of a cache), and some browsers give me a 404, with error details "Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: A-v1.1.zip".

I am *not* using CloudFront.
Also, Cache-Control is set to max-age=120.

Did I make a mistake?
Or is there anything I need to do to make the change in redirection effective?
(I have already checked the metatags in S3, they are correct.)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The gold standard for troubleshooting web requests is the command line utility `curl` with the `-v` option, which shows the request and response headers.  Try that with the URL that should be redirecting and check the `Location` response header to be sure that S3 is currently returning the URL you expect.  Typically it would update very quickly after a change, so verify that, first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! great advice!